# The effect of incorrect prototype.constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

When we declare a javascript function `Person`,`Person.prototype.constructor === Person`.Then we rewrite the `Person.prototype`,the constructor is `Object` other than `Person`.

```
function Person() {
   this.name = 'Kitty';
}
console.log(Person.prototype.constructor === Person) // true
Person.prototype = {
    say:function(){
       return 'Hi';
    }
}
console.log(Person.prototype.constructor === Person) // false
console.log(Person.prototype.constructor === Object) // true
```

So it's better to reset constructor to itself.
My question is what is the actual effects of incorrect `Person.prototype.constructor`? It seems work fine with the committed line.

```
// Person.prototype.constructor = Person
var me = new Person();
console.log(me instanceof Person) // true
console.log(me.name) // Kitty
console.log(me.say()) // Hi
console.log(me.constructor === Person) // false
```

More generally,what does `prototype.constructor` exactly do?

Comment: So why does the code works fine with incorrect `prototype.constructor`?

Comment: It works because you're calling the function `Person`, which is still defined and visible in the name space.  `var q = Object.create(Person.prototype); q.name === "Kitty" // false`